# Show English text with Malayalam Ascii Font in Android?

Tags: unicode, blackberry, ascii

Hi I am developing an application to display Malayalam words in my application and using a  Malayalam font for this purpose. And I am getting the right output . But when I try to display some English letters along with Malayalam it doesn't the font i used is Thoolika.Ttf.
 That is the input i given is "Y¢j¤lcÉd¤j«: one "
The required Output is : "തിരുവനന്തപുരം:One"
But  I am getting output as :"തിരുവനന്തപുരം: സഷഫ"
 What is the problem here

Comment: What's the encoding you use and does it support mixing English and Malayalam?  What are the bytes which result in this display string?

Comment: UTF-8 encoding is used. English letter A is equvalent to Malayalam Leter അ

Comment: I have this same issue. Have u got solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

This font uses a "visual encoding": you write the letter `A`, and it is logically a Latin letter `A`, but it is rendered on-screen to look like `അ`.

Visually-encoded fonts are a relic of the days before proper Unicode support and you should not use them today. One of their many bad points is, as you have discovered, that you can't write Latin letters in the same font. To write a mixture of Latin and Malayalam when all you have is a visual-encoded font, you will have to switch fonts for each stretch of text.

I'd recommend dropping this font and getting a Unicode font with support for the proper Malayalam code points, so that for the shape `അ` you are using a real logical U+0D05 MALAYALAM LETTER A and not U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A. Then you can mix up Latin and Malayalam (and indeed any other language the system has a font for) freely.

Comment: USE SpannaleString Builder

Answer (score 3):

Well, you cant...! as **bobince** said, you cant mix to show english + "malayalam in ascii font" ("visually encoded") in a field with font face as this ascii font (here "Thoolika.ttf")...

You can achieve that only if the text is Unicode encoded (UTF-8)...
Try with Anjali old lipi (Unicode) font. Start here :: [smc.org.in/](http://smc.org.in/)

Comment: that is helpful. Thank you.